# Error while compiling libimobiledevice in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, linux, gcc, makefile

Actually, I was compiling [libimobiledevice](https://libimobiledevice.org/) for the second time. I had used it long ago. But this time I encountered an error like given below:

```
Configuration for libimobiledevice 1.3.1:
-------------------------------------------

  Install prefix: .........: /usr/local
  Debug code ..............: no
  Python bindings .........: yes
  SSL support backend .....: OpenSSL

  Now type 'make' to build libimobiledevice 1.3.1,
  and then 'make install' for installation.

make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice'
Making all in common
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/common'
  CC       socket.lo
  CC       thread.lo
  CC       debug.lo
  CC       userpref.lo
  CC       utils.lo
  CCLD     libinternalcommon.la
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/common'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/src'
  CC       idevice.lo
  CC       service.lo
  CC       property_list_service.lo
  CC       device_link_service.lo
  CC       lockdown.lo
  CC       afc.lo
afc.c: In function ‘afc_make_link’:
afc.c:1012:11: warning: unused variable ‘type’ [-Wunused-variable]
 1012 |  uint64_t type = htole64(linktype);
      |           ^~~~
  CC       file_relay.lo
  CC       notification_proxy.lo
  CC       installation_proxy.lo
  CC       sbservices.lo
  CC       mobile_image_mounter.lo
  CC       screenshotr.lo
  CC       mobilesync.lo
  CC       mobilebackup.lo
  CC       house_arrest.lo
  CC       mobilebackup2.lo
  CC       misagent.lo
  CC       restore.lo
  CC       diagnostics_relay.lo
  CC       heartbeat.lo
  CC       debugserver.lo
debugserver.c: In function ‘debugserver_client_set_argv’:
debugserver.c:582:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘asprintf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  582 |   asprintf(&prefix, ",%d,%d,", (int)strlen(argv[i]) * 2, i);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
debugserver.c:603:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘asprintf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  603 |   asprintf(&prefix, ",%d,%d,", arg_hexlen, i);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC       webinspector.lo
  CC       mobileactivation.lo
  CC       preboard.lo
  CC       companion_proxy.lo
  CC       syslog_relay.lo
  CCLD     libimobiledevice-1.0.la
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/src'
Making all in include
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/include'
Making all in cython
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/cython'
/usr/bin/cython -I/usr/local/include/plist/cython -I../src -o imobiledevice.c imobiledevice.pyx
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/cython/imobiledevice.pxd
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
warning: imobiledevice.pxd:6:4: Exception already a builtin Cython type
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/cython'
  CC       imobiledevice_la-imobiledevice.lo
  CCLD     imobiledevice.la
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/cython'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/cython'
Making all in tools
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/tools'
  CC       idevice_id-idevice_id.o
  CCLD     idevice_id
  CC       ideviceinfo-ideviceinfo.o
  CCLD     ideviceinfo
  CC       idevicename-idevicename.o
  CCLD     idevicename
  CC       idevicepair-idevicepair.o
  CCLD     idevicepair
  CC       idevicesyslog-idevicesyslog.o
  CCLD     idevicesyslog
  CC       ideviceimagemounter-ideviceimagemounter.o
  CCLD     ideviceimagemounter
  CC       idevicescreenshot-idevicescreenshot.o
  CCLD     idevicescreenshot
/usr/bin/ld: idevicescreenshot-idevicescreenshot.o: undefined reference to symbol 'log10@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:769: idevicescreenshot] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice/tools'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:455: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ghosthackz/ios/libimobiledevice'
make: *** [Makefile:385: all] Error 2
```

I am using a bash script for automation:

```
#!/bin/bash

function build() {
    libs=( "libplist" "libusbmuxd" "libimobiledevice" "usbmuxd" "libirecovery" \
                "ideviceinstaller" "libideviceactivation" "idevicerestore" "ifuse" )

    buildlibs() {
        for i in "${libs[@]}"
        do
            git clone https://github.com/libimobiledevice/${i}.git
            cd $i
            ./autogen.sh
            make && sudo make install
            cd ..
        done
    }

    buildlibs
    if [[ -e $(which ldconfig) ]]; then
        ldconfig
    else
        echo "done"
    fi
}

build
if [[ $(uname) == 'Linux' ]]; then
    sudo ldconfig
fi
```

I have installed the following build packages:

```
sudo apt-get install \
    build-essential \
    checkinstall \
    git \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    libtool-bin \
    libplist-dev \
    libusbmuxd-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    usbmuxd \
    cython
```

What am I doing wrong can you please help? This is my first question. Sorry if I made the question including too much detail.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, that's more suited to a bug report. For a programming question, you'd have to extract a [mcve] first.

Comment: The only actual error appears to be that `-lm` is not included in the link for idevicescreenshot, or perhaps that it appears too early in the link command.  That seems to implicate a flaw in the build system -- either the configuration script or the makefile.  If you are confident that you have followed the build instructions faithfully then that would be something to take up with the project's maintainers, though it ought to be relatively easy to patch, too.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/pull/1087) in libimobiledevice which required it to link with `libm`. That's been [fixed a couple of days ago](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/commit/9c3dd915ea00ce33d6dee359bcef963a586aaf05), so I'd recommend you get the latest sources from GitHub and try again. That should fix it.